# Не запускается скрипт Python в командной строке

Tags: python, cmd

когда я запускаю любой код через IDLE то всё работает без проблем, но если я пытаюсь запустить код двойным кликом по файлу то cmd появляется буквально на мгновение и сразу исчезает. С pach у меня всё в порядке я проверял. я ещё новичок поэтому объясните по проще как это починить.

Comment: в конце своего кода напиши
```
input('сюда можно свой текст вставить:D')
```
так код не будет закрываться сразу, а будет ждать нажатие клавиши Enter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скрипт отрабатывает и закрывается так все действия выполнены(или произошла ошибка но думаю не Ваш случай).
Можно добавить в конец файла строку `input("Пауза..")` тогда скрипт будет ожидать пользовательского ввода и закроется по интеру.

Или вызвать системную паузу:

```py
import os

# Ваш код

os.system("pause") # Для Windows
```

Тогда будет предложение нажать любую кнопку.

Answer (score 0):

Суть в чём.. Когда ты открываешь скрипт через уже открытую консоль, она выполняет работу и приходит в изначальное состояние т.е готовая принять команды. А когда ты открываешь её через bat или cmd она открывается с целью только выполнения твоего скрипта, и как скрипт заканчивает свою работу, её заканчивает и командная строка